# Build/Buy 128 Button Matrix

Tags: gpio, connection, connectors

I want to build a system where roughly 100 Buttons can be pressed and start a specific command. Pricecly I want to digitalize a good old Piano, at least as good as possible. As far as google led me what Iam searching for is a button Matrix, and the Pi seems to be able to work with 128 Buttons max(?).

To save me alot of wiring or ordering an expensive custom board I was looking for something similar to this (this is for andruino)
https://www.spikenzielabs.com/learn/button64.html
So an off the shelf addon board that allows me to connect 128 buttons. (the one in the link only works with 64 and i guess i cant use two at the same time) also for price sake I would prefer using only one PI/Arduino. Some master/slave setup would be to complex for a beginner like me.

If there is no of the shelf solution Iam also fine with soldering a little myself or ordering a custom board. I have seen examples for 4x4 matrixes but so far none for 128 buttons, how would something like this be wired/connected to the pi?

After the hardwaree there would also be the slight Software issue. I guess I can blow up the code for a 4x4 keypad but especially since pressing several buttons at once would be a nice to have feature this might not work for me. Any nodes to good code basis or exemples would be appriciated.

Lastly (but maybe most importantly) I havent found any project online that does basically the same (Piano digitalisation) but Iam not the fist one to do it for sure, so a link to such a project would be a great help as well.

Thanks alot guys and sorry for the long text.

Greeting
Georg

Comment: This question is of topic, but FYI a matrix will make a poor piano - only 1 key can be pressed at a time.

Comment: @Milliways thanks for the quick response. Why is my question off topic?
depending on how complex the alternative is I would have to live with a poor piano ;) what would be a better alternative to a matrix?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hello, have you considered that the Pi already supports a very common and relatively cheap array of buttons with 104 or more keys and even some LEDs: the humble USB keyboard. Just sayin'.

Comment: Also worth bearing in mind that the very essence of a piano is the ability to play the notes at varying volume.  Switches will only give you "on" or "off".  You'll have a poor man's harpsichord at best.

Comment: @RogerJones yeah this idea als poped in my mined but I assumed that catching the inputs in the code may be difficult (?). and also has the Numblock Bumbers different ASCII Code then the regular numbers? but besides that yeah its pretty much exactly what i want. It just doesnt seem like the best way to do it, but its surely an option.

Comment: @MarkSmith Thats true, i could use different sensors but for V1 i will live with just buttons. Its more about learning and trying a little. Also A piano jukebox (so just playing songs) what be nice as well and probably simpler.